# Excel won't get data from Microsoft Query

Tags: sql-server, excel

I used Microsoft Query and wrote a query to our MSSQL database. The query works great in MS Query. It's about 59,000 rows and 9 columns of data. When I close MS Query and it goes to import the data into Excel, it says: "Getting Data" for a few seconds and then just disappears. No data ever actually shows, but it's almost like Excel seems to think there is something there.

I've tried on Excel 2007 and 2010, but both do the same thing. I've read that Excel 2007/10 can handle up to a 1,000,000 row query, so I'm not sure why it's not working here.

Comment: please post the SQL Query.

Comment: Have you tried doing it as an ADO Recordset in VBA, then using the _Range.Copyfromrecordset Recordset:=rs_ ?

Comment: You can view the query here: http://pastebin.com/fufFsREm

Comment: I gave an answer below, but I think you need to create a stored proc on your server, and use an ADO recordset or Command to retrieve the dataset into Excel VBA, the use **CopyFromRecordset**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an ADO method in VBA that might work...

```
sub getData()
dim adoRS as object ' ADODB.Recordset
dim adoConn as object ' ADODB.Connection
dim sConnStr as string

set adors=createobject("adodb.recordset")
set adoConn=createobject("ADODB.connection")

with adocn
.provider="MSSQL"
.cursorlocation=3 ' aduseclient
.connectionstring=sConnstr ' get from UDL file in Windows Explorer
.open
end with

with adors
.source="SELECT * FROM table"
.activeconnection=adocn
.cursortype=1 ' adopenkeyset
.locktype=1 ' adlockreadonly
.cursorlocation=3 ' aduseclient
.open
end with

range("A1").copyfromrecordset adors

end sub
```

I hope that helps

Philip

Comment: maybe you need to put your query in a Stored Procedure, then using an ADO Recordset or ADO Command to return the data, and put it in the worksheet with **CopyFromRecordset**

Comment: I'll have to learn how to use VBA I guess! Thanks for your help. I'll try and figure out how to implement it.

Comment: please choose my answer if it has helped